# Where are textures stored in 3DSMax?

Tags: 3ds-max

I can't find the physical location where textures are stored within 3DSMax 2014.

Answer (score 2):

From the 2010 version, the max does not install textures directories. You can search for the desired texture on the site: http://www.cgtextures.com.